# Unable to Import to MacOS Photos from external drive

Tags: macos, photos, catalina, import

Getting non-tech spouse setup to sort 20 years of pics using Photos.    Worked well for the first four years of pics, then only part of year five was imported.  Tried "repair photo library" and "create new photo library and import to it" without success, so...

[God forbid a single app could be reinstalled.`</editorial>` ]

From a clean install (recovery mode: remove Data disk, erase system disk, reinstall macOS ) to Catalina (macOS 10.15.4 19E266 March 24, 2020), able to import anywhere from 1 to several hundred pictures before Photos stops showing the imported pictures and throws "Cannot import nn items" and for each pic file "Invalid: The operation couldn't be completed (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1)".  Tried File-Import, tried drag n drop.  Tried different external hard drive.  Tried copying pic files to mac before importing.  Might have tried a few other things...

After three clean installs with similar failures, here I am.

[image: PHPhotosErrorDomain error]

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem when trying to copy photos to Photos app from an external hard drive fromatted as Case-sensitive Mac OS Extended Journaled.

Comment: My drives were formatted exFAT,, to copy from Win XP to Mac.   Experienced same failure on 2019 16" MBP.  Third call with Apple scheduled 4/1, hoping for solution.

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Apple devs captured Photos app data (diagnostic dump?) and will call again 09Apr.  They do not think issue is with the external drives.

Comment: Same problem is happening to me trying to import pictures from the macOS APFS partition on 10.15.4. Don’t think this has to do with external drives or partition types specifically. Seems like Photos is just full of bugs in its current state.